# How can I create electric fileds of an electric charge with latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw electric field lines of an electric charge but I dont know how! Is there anybody to help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you add a sketch of the desired result?

Comment: There is a specific package called `pst-electricfield`: https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-electricfield. Do you know?

Comment: Thanks a lot I did'nt know that!

Comment: @SAM We don't know what you want to draw, but if you prefer to have your own drawing you can draw with an online tool that it exports to `TikZ-pgf`: https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: Try `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \node[fill,red,circle,draw,inner sep=7pt](C){}; \foreach \X in {0,10,...,350} {\draw (C) -- (\X:pi);} \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}`. If you want something else, please edit your question to clarify,